# Assigning button to row in JXTreeTable

Tags: java, jtable, jxtreetable

I am trying to assign a button to a row in a JXTreeTable instance.
It's working, but when I expand a row, the button is staying on it's original place. I can't post any pictures cuz I have no 10 reputation points... Example:

In this case, last names is a expandable row, and the button is in the third row.

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║   Property    ║          Value           ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ Name          ║ Mark                     ║
║ + Last names  ║ [name_1, name_2, name_3] ║
║ Age           ║ 30[button here]          ║ <------- button is now here
║ Length        ║ 1.80                     ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

If we expand 'Last names', It will look like this:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║   Property    ║          Value           ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ Name          ║ Mark                     ║
║ + Last names  ║ [name_1, name_2, name_3] ║
║ index 1       ║ name_1[button here]      ║ <------ button stays at row 3
║ index 2       ║ name_2                   ║
║ index 3       ║ name_3                   ║
║ Age           ║ 30                       ║ <------ button should be here
║ Length        ║ 1.80                     ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

Does anyone knows how I can accomplish this? So that the button will move to its correct place where it should be when expanding a row?

Comment: It's the same process as rendering buttons in a JTable, you need to create a cell render/editor capable of performing the job you want....

Comment: I already have a custom cell editor and renderer. I am rendering a JPanel in each row with a JTextField and a JButton. But whatever I try, the button will stick to it's original row.

Comment: Well without an example of what you are doing that de on starters your problem, that's the best guess I can make

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. I was identifying rows by their index. Now I am identifying then by their property names. Thanks though.